# Slow SQL query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I have already read similar questions, but it does not help me.

I have query

```
SELECT `login`, 
   `photo`, 
   `username`, 
   `user`.`id`, 
   `name`, 
   `msg_info` 
FROM   `user` 
       LEFT JOIN `friends` 
              ON `friends`.`child` = `user`.`fb_id` 
WHERE  `friends`.`parent` = '1111' 
ORDER  BY `msg_info` DESC
```

Which tooks **0.7411** seconds (and even more)

It shows **158 total** rows (ok i can limit it, but query still slow)

Each of tables ***friends*** and ***user*** has more than 200.000 rows

What can i do for query go faster?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use order by?

Comment: Pointless using LEFT JOIN there- your where clause makes it run as INNER JOIN anyway

Comment: Qualify all coumns, so we know which table a column belongs to, i.e. tablename.columnname everywhere.

Comment: MassiveOwl, you are absolutely right, i removed the ordering and everything became wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: @CaiusJard maybe he needs to put the friends.parent = 1111 in the ON clause instead of the WHERE clause and still wants a left join.

Comment: @AnyUser If you need that `ORDER BY` for your reporting, then removing it isn't wonderful, because then you have unsorted data :-)

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, yes, but it was not necessary.

Comment: Which table is `msg_info` in?  It is critical to several of the Answers.  When writing a `JOIN`, please qualify each column with the table name or table alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments pointed out, your left join is really not different than the following inner join query:

```
SELECT
    login,
    photo,
    username,
    user.id,
    name,
    msg_info
FROM user u
INNER JOIN friends f
    ON f.child = u.fb_id
WHERE
    f.parent = '1111'
ORDER BY
    msg_info DESC;
```

We can try adding an index to the `friends` table on `(parent, child, name, msg_info, ...)`.  I am not sure which other columns belong to `friends`, but the basic idea is to create an index on `parent`, to speed up the `WHERE` clause, and hopefully take advantage of low cardinality on the `parent` column.  Then, we include the `child` column to speed up the join.  We also include all the other columns in the select clause to let the index cover the other columns we need.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON friends (parent, child, name, msg_info, ...);
```

Comment: If any of those index columns is `TEXT`, the `CREATE` will fail.  And, 'covering' has diminishing returns when you get past about 5 columns.  Suggest only `INDEX(parent)`.  If `msg_info` is in `friends`, then do `INDEX(parent, msg_info)`.

Comment: @RickJames OK, but it's not clear to me that MySQL would use the index you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrVimes suggeted, *sometimes* adding a condition to the JOIN clause can make a big difference:

```
SELECT login, photo, username, user.id, name, msg_info
FROM user u
INNER JOIN friends f ON f.child = u.fb_id AND f.parent = '1111'
ORDER BY msg_info DESC;
```

Assuming, of course, all your PK and FKs are properly defined and indexed.